# Limited processes when using SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server-2008, vbscript, sql-agent-job

I have a VBScript file which calls another script for parallel executing.

The first VBScript's name is `Root.vbs`:

```vb
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next

Sub ParallelExecute(idx,strlog)
    Dim objShell, strCmd
    Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    strCmd = "%comspec% /c cscript  C:\TestVbs\test.vbs " & idx & " " & strlog
    objShell.Run strCmd
    objShell = Nothing
End Sub

Dim intIdx
Dim strLog, strLog1, strLog2
strLog = "C:\TestVbs\Log\Root"
'parallel executing
For intIdx = 0 to 150
    strLog1 = strLog & intIdx & ".txt"
    Call ParallelExecute(intIdx, strLog1)
Next
Wscript.Quit

Sub WriteLog(strLogPath, idx)   
    Dim objFile, objFso, strContent
    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strLogPath, 8, True)
    strContent = idx
    Dim zzz
    For zzz=0 to 2
        objFile.WriteLine(FormatDateTime(Now) & "    ROOT    " & strContent)
    Next
    objFile.Close
End Sub
```

The second VBScript's name is `test.vbs`:

```vb
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next

Dim idx, time, strLogPath
idx = WScript.Arguments(0)
strLogPath = "C:\TestVbs\Log\" & idx & ".txt"
Call WriteLog(strLogPath,idx)
Wscript.Quit

Sub WriteLog(strLogPath, idx)   
    Dim objFile, objFso, strContent
    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strLogPath, 8, True)
    strContent = idx
    Dim intIdx
    For intIdx=0 to 10
        objFile.WriteLine(FormatDateTime(Now) & "    SUB     " & strContent)
        Wscript.Sleep 6000
    Next
    objFile.Close
End Sub
```

And I have a SQL Agent Script:

```sql
USE msdb
GO
--
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @filename nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @csCommand nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT

SET @filename = 'C:\TestVbs\Log\log.txt'
SET @ReturnCode = 0
SET @csCommand = 'cscript "C:\TestVbs\Root.vbs"' 

-- Create Job
EXEC @ReturnCode = sp_add_job 
    @job_name = N'JOBTEST' -- Job name 
    , @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

-- Create Job Step1
EXEC @ReturnCode = sp_add_jobstep
@job_name = N'JOBTEST' -- Must be the same as the name of job has just created above 
, @step_name = N'JOBTEST' -- Step name
, @on_success_action= 1 
, @subsystem=N'CmdExec' -- Specify that this step calls a cmd command
, @command=@csCommand -- Cmd command
, @output_file_name= @filename  -- Specify log file name
, @flags=2 -- Appending log to existing file
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

EXEC @ReturnCode = sp_add_jobschedule
@job_id=@jobId -- Specify the jobID that this scheduler will plan for 
, @name=N'JOBTEST_SCH' -- Schedule name
, @freq_type=4  
, @freq_interval=1
, @active_start_time=030000
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

-- Add job to Server
EXEC @ReturnCode = sp_add_jobserver
@job_name = N'JOBTEST' -- Add to jobserver
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

When I use the commandline to execute `Root.vbs` script, all of processes (root and sub process) are created and run normally, but when I use the SQL agent to execute `Root.vbs` script, some processes (sub process) are not created.

I think sub commandline is limited by SQL Server, but i don't know how to configure SQL Agent.

Comment: You have `On Error Resume Next` in both VBScripts, which will hide almost any error you get. Remove those lines or at least add some error logging, so you get an idea of what's going on.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: Thanks for your reply. I changed "objShell.Run strCmd" become "objShell.Exec strCmd" in Root.vbs file, It worked

Comment: Replacing `Run` with `Exec` shouldn't make a difference.